# Finding the parent of a node in a Binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, parent

I am trying to write a method to find the parent of a given node. Here's my method.
I created a `BinaryNode` object r which initially refers to root.

```
    public BinaryNode r=root;
    public BinaryNode parent(BinaryNode p){
    BinaryNode findParent=p;        
        if (isRoot(findParent) || r==null){
                return null;
        }
        else{
            if(r.left==findParent || r.right==findParent)
                return r;
            else{
                if (r.element<findParent.element)
                    return parent(r.right);
                else
                    return parent(r.left);
            }
        }
    }
```

THis code  doesn't work properly .I think that's because r is a null object.Because when I do

```
if (isRoot(findParent) || r==null){
                System.out.println(r==null);
                return null;}
```

`r==null` evaluates to `true`.How come that happen because I have inserted nodes as

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        BinaryTree t=new BinaryTree();
        t.insert(5);
        t.insert(t.root,4);
        t.insert(t.root,6);
        t.insert(t.root,60);
        t.insert(t.root,25);
        t.insert(t.root,10);
```

and the root is not null.
Can some one please point out why that happens and if what I am trying to do in order to find the parent  node is logically correct.

Comment: How do you call the find parent mehtod? Which arguments do you provide?

Comment: @wastl: findParent is not a method.It is a binaryNode that stores the node that we need to find parent of

Comment: Sorry, i meant the parent(BinaryNode) method

Comment: @wastl:If I want to find the parent of node situated at left of root, the method can be called as ` parent(root.left)`

Comment: Have you checked if isRoot(findParent) evaluates to true?

Comment: If I call as `parent(root.left)` method isRoot() evaluates to false,which is correct as it is not the root

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you MUST keep track of your current node, while keeping the node who's parent you want to find. And as far as I understand your code, you keep the variable, but never change it
I'd recommend using a helper function. This would look something like that:

```
public BinaryNode parent(BinaryNode p){
    parentHelper(root,p)
}
private BinaryNode parentHelper(BinaryNode currentRoot, BinaryNode p) {        
    if (isRoot(p) || currentRoot==null){
            return null;
    }
    else{
        if(currentRoot.left==p || currentRoot.right==p)
            return currentRoot;
        else {
            if (currentRoot.element<p.element) {
                return parentHelper(currentRoot.right,p);
            }
            else {
                return parentHelper(currentRoot.left,p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the given answer.I realized that I was never changing the current variable and found a way I think that would fix that.At the start I am trying to get the root node to the variable r .For that I have `public BinaryNode r=root;` just outside parent() method.Then to check I did                                                 `public BinaryNode parent(BinaryNode p){
 System.out.println("r"+r.element);`                          where I get a null pointer exception

Comment: That means r is a null object that's why  `if (isRoot(findParent) || r==null){` gets evaluated always and there it returns false and the rest of the code isn't even run.**Why does r become a null object**.This is my binaryTree implementation.                         `public class BinaryTree { private BinaryNode root;  public BinaryTree(){  root= null;}BinaryTree(int nodeValue){
  root=new BinaryNode(nodeValue);}`                          and I insert elements to it as `t.insert(5);
  t.insert(t.root,4);`

Comment: Your code runs I think the lines `return parent(currentRoot.right,p);` should change as `return parentHelper(currentRoot.right,p);`

Answer (score 2):

I compared value to value because I didn't define the way to compare the nodes.

```
    public static Node FindParent(Node root, Node node)
    {
        if (root == null || node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if ( (root.Right != null && root.Right.Value == node.Value) || (root.Left != null && root.Left.Value == node.Value))
        {
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            Node found = FindParent(root.Right, node);
            if (found == null)
            {
                found = FindParent(root.Left, node);
            }
            return found;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two parameters: One for the current node and one for the node being searched.

Comment: While this is correct, this does not explain _what_ is wrong with OP's code and _why_ the OP should do this. Adding these will make a better answer no doubt.

Comment: Well, the problem looks like a homework assignment, so I did not want to give too many hints ;)

Comment: Then post this as a comment. I think this is too short (both length-wise and matter-wise) for an answer.

Comment: @peq :I thought  r acts as a variable that keeps care of current node

Comment: @peq:This is not a homework assignment.I am learning data structures and under that I am doing trees. I just tried out writing a method to find parent just to help myself learn it

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to find out parent node using a stack Data Structures.

```
Stack<TreeNode> parentStack = new Stack<TreeNode>();

public static void inOrderTraversal(TreeNode root){
            if(root != null){
                if(parentStack.size()==0){
                    parentStack.push(root);
                }
                if(root.getLeftChild()!=null){
                    parentStack.push(root); 
                    inOrderTraversal(root.getLeftChild());  
                }
                parent = parentStack.pop();
                System.out.println(root.getNodeValue()+"'s parent is "+parent.getNodeValue());
                if(root.getRightChild()!=null){
                    parentStack.push(root);
                    inOrderTraversal(root.getRightChild());
                }
            }
            else{
                if(root==null){System.err.println("Can't process a empty root tree");}
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to delegate as much work as I can to lower-level components, in this case the Node class.  Re: finding a node's parent, this is how I do it ...

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::parent (const Node<T>* node) 
{
    if (node)
    {
        if (*node < *this)
        {
            if (left && (*node < *left))
                return left->parent (node);
            return this;
        }
        if (*node > *this)
        {
            if (right && (*right > *node))
                return right->parent (node);
            return this;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```